# Abstract class has abstract nested class; always have to cast the abstract nested class before using it

Tags: java, oop, generics, inheritance

Sorry for the confusing title. I couldn't find an answer online for weeks, maybe i just don't know how to word it properly.
I'm a trainee, so anything helps, even if it's simply improving my question :)

So what's the deal?
I have an abstract class, that does something with different types of POJOs, let's call it `AbstractImporter`

To "do that something", some information is required, which is stored in a **nested** class called `AbstractCache`

In addition to the common data used in all imports, some type-specific data would be saved in the implementation of the cache.
So, if you want to implement `AbstractImporter`, you also have to implement `AbstractCache`, that's the idea. (and is enforced by the actual code)

The goal would be to have the right type of cache available during an import.
However, currently i have to **cast** my `cache` parameter to the correct type by hand...
My code looks somewhat as follows:

Here's the abstract Class

```
abstract class AbstractImporter<D extends ImportData> {

    abstract protected boolean importObject(D dataSet, AbstractCache cache);
    
    abstract protected class AbstractCache{
        ...
    }
}
```

And here's the implementation

```
class FooImporter extends AbstractImporter <FooImportData> {

    @Override
    protected boolean importObject(FooImportData dataSet, AbstractCache cache){
        cache = (FooCache) cache; //note how this needs to be casted manually
        ...
    }

    private FooCache extends AbstractCache{
        ...
    }
}
```

But i'm not happy with that. There must be a way to get the correct implementation of `AbstractCache` in as a parameter, without having to cast it.

I've tried adding another type-parameter in `AbstractImporter`, like this:

```
abstract class AbstractImporter<D extends AbstractImportData, C extends AbstractCache> {

    abstract protected boolean importObject(D dataSet, C cache);
```

but then, in the implementation, my IDE (IntelliJ) marks the new type parameter as an error **without telling me why...**

```
class FooImporter extends AbstractImporter <FooImportData, *FooCache*> {
                                          //                ^ Error
```

So here are my questions - again, anything would be appreciated.

1. How would i have to refactor my code to always get the correct type of cache in my `importObject` method, straight from the header?
2. What other flaws do you see with this design?
3. Why do i get an error with my *"cache as type parameter"* approach?
4. Are there any things I phrased incorrectly, or any terms i didn't use correctly?

Comment: You'd need to move `AbstractCache` into it's own java file, else you'll run into a deadlock. Additionally you'd need to qualify inner classes, by the enclosing class name. i.e. use `FooImport.FooCache` in the generics

Comment: at last if you want to use `FooCache` in the generics, you need to make it not private

Comment: this feedback helped me not only get onto the track i wanted, but also understand the whole situation a lot better. thank you very much! ☺

Comment: it is not the easiest topic, and your example is also not the most intricate one. But I'm glad that I could help